# Inserting column name headers into a Python list

Tags: python, list, csv, dictionary

I am trying to insert column headers into a Python list. The csv file I am using does not have column names and the data is separated by commas. I am trying to write this program so that I don't have to insert column names into the csv file every time I make the weekly maps in ArcGIS. I could also turn the csv into a dictionary if needed. Either way would be fine. I have this code so far which produces a dataset that is useable. I know how to reference columns in a dictionary by column name. But the same method doesn't seem to work for inserting column names into a column position.

```
import os
os.chdir('C:\Users\####\Desktop')
fileData = open('SOUTH_06_01_2015_SECFILE.CSV','rb')

def dataHeader():
    headerLine = fileData.readline()
    valueList = headerLine.split(',')
    yield valueList

def dataBody():
    for line in fileData.readlines():
        segmentLine = line.split(',')
        yield segmentLine[0:6]

def dataPrinter():
    gen1 = dataHeader()
    gen2 = dataBody()
    print'\n'
    for row in gen2:
        print row
dataPrinter()
```

Comment: Yes at the time that I was using the code that I posted I was not printing gen1. I was just using the output from gen2.

Comment: So what you want to do is to write a program that gets names from the user and sets them as the header of your csv file?

Comment: Yes that's what I want to do bshuster. Just printing out gen1 and gen2 prints just the top line of the dataset, and the rest of the dataset below without any reference to the columns.

Comment: So basically, at this point just calling headerLine is pretty much useless. And renaming the columns in headerLine deletes that data from the dataset body which is no good. I could turn headerLine into column names, sure, but then that line of data is lost.

Comment: sorry I meant valueList not headerLine/

Comment: Please, review my answer. Let me know if I am missing anything.

Comment: Are you just trying to write a header?

Comment: Yes I am trying to write a header.

Comment: @hollow_Victory I don't understand. Doesn't my solution work for you?

Comment: Sorry buddy im at work juggling multiple things and I got pulled away to do something. Im back now though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming, the user inserts the names of the columns and the csv file does not have column names, this should do the job.

```
def dataHeader(columns_no):
    columns = []
    for i in range(columns_no):
        text = raw_input("Enter column #%d name> " % i)
        columns.append(text)
    return columns


def dataBody(columns_no):
    segmentLines = []
    for line in fileData.readlines():
        segmentLine = line.split(',')
        segmentLines.append(segmentLine[:columns_no])
    return segmentLines


def dataPrinter():
    columns_no = 6
    gen1 = dataHeader(columns_no)
    gen2 = dataBody(columns_no)
    print ','.join(gen1)
    for row in gen2:
        print ','.join(row)


dataPrinter()
```

Comment: Well here is the output from running the code above:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/####/Desktop/column_namer_csv_06_10_2015.py", line 27, in <module>
    dataPrinter()
  File "C:/Users/####/Desktop/column_namer_csv_06_10_2015.py", line 24, in dataPrinter
    print ','.join(gen1)
TypeError

Comment: I do like the raw input of the column names but I think what may need to be done is to create the header then zip the header to the body according to how each is separated by a character, like a comma?

Comment: I fixed the error you got; you want to insert the header in one line. Like: "first-name, last-name, zipcode" instead of "first-name"<enter>"lastname"<enter>"zipcode"<enter>

Comment: I forgot to return the `columns` in the `headerBody`

Comment: Ah yes the headerBody function does not return anything

Comment: I put a return statement into the headerBody function but now it returns and error: File "C:/Users/U2970/Desktop/column_namer_csv_06_10_2015.py", line 27, in dataPrinter
    print ','.join(row)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found

Comment: Can you print `row` before doing `','.join(row)` and copy it to the comment. I want to know what `row` is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80206/discussion-between-bshuster13-and-hollow-victory).

Comment: The program works great but im trying to make it so that printing function can return something. How can this be done? Im not sure how to do this since it would have to return two datasets.

Comment: i am not sure i understand you. can you edit your question with your new request. please enter another comment so i know you have done that.

Comment: Ok I made a new request, or asked a new question here on the site.